# sockaddr.sin_port = 1337 doesn't match the "real" opened port

Tags: c, linux, sockets, port, sockaddr-in

I am trying to make a very simple server that accept a connection.

```
int sock, serv;
struct sockaddr_in in_sock;
serv = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
in_sock.sin_addr.s_addr = 0;
in_sock.sin_port = 1337;
in_sock.sin_family = AF_INET;
bind(serv, (struct sockaddr *)&in_sock, sizeof(in_sock)); 
listen(serv, 0);
client = accept(serv, 0, 0);
```

However when trying to connect to 127.0.0.1:1337, I get a connection refused message :

> (UNKNOWN) [127.0.0.1] 1337 (?) : Connection refused

However a simple `netstat -tcpan` shows me that a port is indeed opened :

> tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:14597           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN

If I set sin_port with much higher ports it seems to work properly though.

What am I missing here ? Why isn't the 1337 port opened ? It seems to be free too.

Comment: you have to use [`htons`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/htons) for the port to switch the byte order

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The port number field in `struct sockaddr_in` is stored in network byte order. This means that you must use `htons()` when storing a value to it:

```
in_sock.sin_port = htons(1337);
```

Otherwise, the port number will be left byte-swapped. Which is exactly what has happened here:

```
 1337 = 0x0539
14597 = 0x3905
```

Answer (score 2):

```
listen(serv, 0);
```

The second argument to `listen` is `backlog` and if we look at the [documentation for listen](https://linux.die.net/man/2/listen) :

> The backlog argument defines the maximum length to which the queue of
>   pending connections for sockfd may grow. If a connection request
>   arrives when the queue is full, the client may receive an error with
>   an indication of ECONNREFUSED or, if the underlying protocol supports
>   retransmission, the request may be ignored so that a later reattempt
>   at connection succeeds.

`ECONNREFUSED` is exactly the error message you're getting because the backlog is full ( it can hold 0 connections so it's always full ).
You should increase that number to at least 1 but a higher amount might be better `listen(serv, 10);`.

Comment: Okay, but then why can I connect to the port shown by netstat ? So a port is opened at the right address, sends me the ECONNREFUSED, but another is opened at the wrong port but I can connect to it ?